# How to email from a webform?

Tags: html, webforms, cgi

I'm working on a website for my small office.

I want to design a form that the user can type in their basic information and the sort of question they need help with, then hit submit.

I would like for this form to then automatically send an email to someone at my office with the contents of the form included.

I was about to start writing this from scratch, but then I realized this has to be a problem that people have already solved.

You can see the page I'm talking about [here](http://www.richardmeinderslaw.com/contact.htm).

Thanks!

Comment: So, you searched on google, found some solutions, tried them but they didn't work, and then you came here... right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a server side language such as [php](http://php.net).

Get the [form data](http://myphpform.com/)

And then use its in built functions such as `mail()` [[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)]